# phonegap custom fonts not working in headers

Tags: android, cordova, webfonts

I have a phonegap app that uses a custom font declared as such in the css:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'NewRockerRegular';
src: url('font/newrocker/NewRocker-Regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('font/newrocker/NewRocker-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-    opentype'), url('font/newrocker/NewRocker-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('font/newrocker/NewRocker-Regular-webfont.svg#NewRockerRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body {
font-family: "NewRockerRegular";
}
```

The app works correctly when testing in Firefox and Chrome.

However when it's compiled into an android app the custom doesn't appear in anything styled with a header tag ( etc)

the font appears correctly on all the body text though.

Comment: The code have to change in call place.The  Error may be here ->body{ font-family}.So, specify any particalar tag,link something in detail div#content,h1,.....

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Android 2.0 or 2.1, it's a [known bug in WebView](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4448).

You can't use external WebFonts on these platforms.

Comment: I'm targeting the 4 series. the odd thing here is that the webfonts are working on body text. just not in header text.